# MS SQLServer Management Studio 2012; Error when running queries after installing S.P. 2

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have searched all over this issue and have found no solutions.

This is the error I am getting:

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Util.BytesToHexString(Byte[], Int32)'.
```

I had no issues with this prior to installing the Windows update for Service Pack 2 and I need this working for my class. My instructor also has no idea how to fix this other than a reinstall which is my **LAST** resort.

I know it is not my queries, as they ran perfect prior to this update.

Please help

Comment: Is that even SqlServer related? Quick search for `System.String Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Util.BytesToHexString` returns nothing.

Comment: I know it returns nothing, I have searched for it. I will try in MySQL, but I am positive that it is only happening in SQLServer

Comment: There is not even anything on the SQLServer site for this error

Comment: Update: It works on MySQL, just not on SQLServer

Comment: However, I need this working on SQLServer.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem, on a clean install of SQL Server 2014 (Express edition) and found that restarting the server itself cured the problem. (In Management Studio, right click on the server at the top of the tree in the object explorer and choose "Restart", or just restart the service...)